# cublasSetVector() vs cudaMemcpy()

Tags: cuda, cublas

I am wondering if there is a difference between:

```
// cumalloc.c - Create a device on the device
HOST float * cudamath_vector(const float * h_vector, const int m)
{
  float *d_vector = NULL;
  cudaError_t cudaStatus;
  cublasStatus_t cublasStatus;

  cudaStatus = cudaMalloc(&d_vector, sizeof(float) * m );

  if(cudaStatus == cudaErrorMemoryAllocation) {
    printf("ERROR: cumalloc.cu, cudamath_vector() : cudaErrorMemoryAllocation");
    return NULL;
  }


  /*    THIS: */ cublasSetVector(m, sizeof(*d_vector), h_vector, 1, d_vector, 1);

  /* OR THAT: */ cudaMemcpy(d_vector, h_vector, sizeof(float) * m, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


  return d_vector;
}
```

`cublasSetVector()` has two arguments `incx` and `incy` and the [documentation says](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#cublassetvector):

> The storage spacing between consecutive elements is given by incx for
>   the source vector x and for the destination vector y.

In the [NVIDIA forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/378993/function-cublassetvector/?offset=2) someone said:

> iona_me: "*incx and incy are strides measured in floats.*"

So does this mean that for `incx = incy = 1` all elements of a `float[]` will be `sizeof(float)`-aligned and for `incx = incy = 2` there would be a `sizeof(float)`-padding between each element?

- Except for those two parameters and the `cublasHandle` - does `cublasSetVector()` anything else what `cudaMalloc()` doesn't do?
- Would it be save to pass a vector/matrix which was **not** created with their respective `cublas*()` function to other CUBLAS functions to manipulate them?

Comment: As long as I know, `cublasSetVector()` will internally call `cudaMemcpy` or its 2D version for strided copies. So I think there is not problem even if the arrays to be set have been created by a `cudaMalloc`. Actually, I have been interchanging cuBLAS and non-cuBLAS instructions with no problem in the recent past.

Comment: @JackOLantern do you want to provide an answer?  I agree with your statements and would upvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a comment in a [thread of the NVIDIA Forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/374456/cublas-vs-cuda-kernel/) provided by Massimiliano Fatica confirming my statement in the above comment (or, saying it better, my comment originated by a recall of having read the post I linked to). In particular

> `cublasSetVector`, `cubblasGetVector`, `cublasSetMatrix`, `cublasGetMatrix` are thin wrappers around `cudaMemcpy` and `cudaMemcpy2D`. Therefore, no significant performance differences are expected between the two sets of copy functions.

Accordingly, you can safely pass any array created by `cudaMalloc` as input to `cublasSetVector`.

Concerning the strides, perhaps there is a misprint in the guide (as of CUDA 6.0), which says that

> The storage spacing between consecutive elements is given by `incx` for the source
>   vector `x` and for the destination vector `y`.

but **perhaps** should be read as

> The storage spacing between consecutive elements is given by `incx` for the source
>   vector `x` and `incy` for the destination vector `y`.

Comment: The CUBLAS documentation of `cublasSetVector` is missing `incy`as noted by @JackOLantern. Compare the description of `cublasGetVector` in the immediately following section. I have filed a bug to get the CUBLAS documentation fixed.